# How to unblock the ip in centos linux

Tags: centos, iptables

I was trying nmap command on my server.
and i have seen that my ip has been blocked.

I can access the server from other computer.

How can unblock my ip in centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i would check to see if you have iptables running `iptables -L` this will show whether you have any firewall restrictions in place.

You can wipe out all the iptables rules by going `iptables -F` but i would strongly recommend you do not do this, the rules where most probably made for a reason and removing them could cause more issues than it solves.

Lastly could you please give a bit more information on what you are trying to do and what ports you are trying to connect to and also is this a internal IP or an External IP you are trying to connect to? at the moment this question seems a little vague so difficult to help you with.

Comment: I have VPS server online , i just ried nmap and was tried to get the OS installed on that for testing. I get some output like fingerprint or something. after that i could not conncet form my company computers. But i can connect to from my home computer using RDP and then putty

Comment: `iptables -F` can be dangerous if the default policy is set to `DROP`.